# Integrate $\int_0^1e^{3y}(-1+e^3)dy$ which step is wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here when trying to integrate $\int_0^1e^{3y}(-1+e^3)dy$

My steps:

1. Factor out the constant so Integrate $(-1+e^3)\int_0^1e^{3y}dy$
2. $u = 3y$ and $du = 3 dy => (-1+e^3)\int_0^3e^{u}du$
3. $(-1+e^3)(e^3) - (-1+e^3)(e^0)$
4. $e^6 - e^3 + 1 - e^3$
5. $e^6 - 2e^3 + 1$

So my answer is wrong and I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here in my computation.
Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to substitute du= 3*dy into the original eqn. Notice, you have just substituted du=dy and this has lead to you getting an incorrect result.

Comment: thanks @IshraaqParvez I've indeed missed that.

Comment: $\int_0^1e^{3y}dy$ at this point, I ask my student, 'what do you wish this was? They want $\int_0^13e^{3y}dy$ . What did you do to get it? Multiply by 3. So $\frac{1}{3}\int_0^13e^{3y}dy$ (i.e. divide outside the integral). For simple integrals, this mimics u-substitution with lower risk of error. Note - you can't multiply by a variable and divide it outside the integral, but the attempt at u-sub would show that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $du = 3dy $ then $dy = \frac{du}3$. You missed this step.

So the value is $\frac{e^6-2e^3+1}{3} = \frac{(e^3-1)^2}{3}$

Comment: indeed, thank you I missed that.